# Creating a Spring Web MVC Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Error on my code

**bookingcontroller.java**

```
import java.net.BindException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;

public class bookingcontroller extends SimpleFormController {
public bookingcontroller() {
    //Initialize controller properties here or 
    //in the Web Application Context

    setCommandClass(Booking.class);
    setCommandName("name");
    setSuccessView("bookingview");
    setFormView("nameview");
}

@Override
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception {
    Booking booking = (Booking) command;
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(getSuccessView());
    mv.addObject("bookingmessages", bookingservices.forminput(booking.getValue()));
    return mv;
}

private bookingservices bs;

public void setbookingservices(bookingservices bs) {
    this.bs = bs;
}
```

> ERROR HERE : @Override

*other file* : applicationContext.xml, dispatcher-servlet.xml, redirect.jsp, web.xml, bookingservices.java, bookingcontroller.java, Booking.java, bookingview.jsp, nameview.jsp

if you need the code, I will show. just ask for the name of file..

Comment: There is no real question to be found here. Please read http://sscce.org and restate your question according to those guidelines. If a self-contained example is too difficult, then you need to copy-paste the exact exception+stacktrace you're seeing and provide A LOT more context information, like what server you're running.

Comment: where is the error detail/stacktrace?

Comment: sorry I can't show the error detail, because something happen on my netbeans..